# Characteristic functions and conditional distributions?

Tags: probability, analysis, probability-theory, fourier-analysis, characteristic-functions

Say X and Y are random variables and we're interested in the conditional distribution of X given Y, can we make this calculation using only characteristic functions in a straightforward manner?

If so how?